# how to find convolution between $f(x)=e^{-2x^2}$ and $g(x)=e^{-2x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I wanted to find the convolution between the two function. By definition I get,
$$(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-2(x-y)^2}e^{-2x^2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-4x^2+4xy-2y^2}dy $$
But I am not able to calculate the given integral.

Comment: Complete the square with respect to $y$ and use the Gaussian integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$(f * g)(x) = e^{-2x^2}   \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-\frac{-(y-x)^2}{2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}}}dy = e^{-2x^2} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} \cdot \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}}}dy = e^{-2x^2}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$$

Where at the last equality we used the fact that measure with density $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$ for $\mu \in \mathbb R,\sigma >0$ is a probability measure

Answer (score 2):

Another way:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-4x^2+4xy-2y^2}dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2(y-x)^2-2x^2}dy
= e^{-2x^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2(y-x)^2}dy
$$

Here,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2(y-x)^2}dy
= \{ z = y-x \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2z^2}dz
= \{ u = \sqrt{2}z \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

Thus,
$$
(f*g)(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-2x^2}.
$$